# URLs provided by GitHub API

Tags: api, github

I noticed when making certain requests to the GitHub API, parts of the JSON response would be URLs.

A lot of times I will find a URL like this:

`https://api.github.com/users/smartguy1196/starred{/owner}{/repo}`

[Example API request using the browser](https://api.github.com/repos/smartguy1196/GHP-CMS/issues?labels=blogpost)

I am trying to understand the latter part of the URL, as I can't figure out how to use it. How do you make use of the part, `{/owner}{/repo}`?

Comment: [GitHub docs](https://developer.github.com/v3/#hypermedia): "All URLs are expected to be proper [RFC 6570](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570) URI templates."  Maybe [read the RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6570)?

Comment: @jwodder that seems to be a good lead, but I'm still not understanding how to use it. It looks like that section is supposed to behave comparable to arguments being passed to a function as parameters. I would assume that if I accessed the URL https://api.github.com/users/smartguy1196/starred/jlord/offline-issues or https://api.github.com/users/smartguy1196/starred?owner=jlord&repo=offline-issues, I would get some sort of useful response, but I don't.